# JAVA return ArrayList object from conditional

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have an interface test class that implements another super-class. In the test class I have a method that is supposed to return an object from an array list; first it's supposed to check the objects in the list to see if it is there, if it is not, it will return a null, otherwise it will return the object that is found. Here is the code I have implemented:

```
public class ProductDBImpl implements ProductDB {

// field declarations
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();



@Override
public Product getProduct(int productId)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // create an iterator for the Arraylist
    Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
    while(pritr.hasNext())
    {
        Product pr = pritr.next();
        if (pritr.next().getId() == productId)
        {
            return pr;
        }
        else
        {

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the error that says:
This method must return a result of type Product.

I was under the impression that by using an iterator and cycling through each element in the list, each element is a type Product. Please help me identify my error.

Comment: Did you really intend to return `null` if the first element in the product list doesn't match on the id?  If so you don't need a while-loop, and if not, you need to wait until your loop is done to return `null`.

Comment: Not the answer to the specific problem, but you're calling `pritr.next()` too many times. Use `if (pr.getId() == productId)`.

Comment: Have You noticed that you're returning an item only if the _next_ item has the searched id? Or in other words: don't call `pritr.next()` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To take care of the error, you need a `return` statement at the end of the `while` loops, as rgettman has pointed out.  But you should also not be returning `null` from within the loop.  You should only return `null` once your loop has completed, and no matching products have been found, as follows:

```
@Override
public Product getProduct(int productId)
{
    Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
    while (pritr.hasNext())
    {
        Product pr = pritr.next();
        if (pritr.next().getId() == productId)
        {
            return pr;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: As rgettman and heenenee and others have suggested I have implemented the code similar to what heenenee has posted with the exception of doing: if (pr.getId() == productId). However, there was mention of returning null if the first product doesn't match productID. Does implementing it the suggested way eliminate this issue?

Comment: Yes, implementing it the suggested way eliminates the issue.

Comment: Understood. Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Your `return` statements are returning a `Product` or `null`, both legal for `getProduct`.  But what if `pritr.hasNext()` returns `false` right away, if there are no `Product`s?  There is no `return` statement if the `while` loop exits for this reason.

Add a `return` statement after the `while` loop.

Also, because you are always returning something in the first iteration of the `while` loop, it's not necessary for it to be a loop.  You can change it to `if` without changing anything else.

But is that really what you want?  It doesn't make sense to return `null` if the first product found doesn't match.  You may want to consider removing that `else` block, to continue searching through the list (and not changing `while` to `if`).

Comment: What would the return statement after the while loop return?

Comment: What makes sense to return if there are no products at all?  I think it would be `null`, because that is also what you return if the first product doesn't match `productId`.

Comment: So I would have a "return null" in the else block, and outside of the while loop?

Answer (score 2):

There is logical mistake in the code you have shared. Your intention is to return the matching product if its found or null if its not. its even better to add a break if you found your product. The correct code would be..

```
public class ProductDBImpl implements ProductDB {

// field declarations
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();



@Override
public Product getProduct(int productId)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // create an iterator for the Arraylist
    Iterator<Product> pritr = products.iterator();
    Product productObj = null;
    while(pritr.hasNext())
    {
        Product pr = pritr.next();
        if (pritr.next().getId() == productId)
        {
            productObj = pr;
            break;
        }
    }
    return productObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, in Java 8 this can be accomplished little differently, without the pesky "null"s and in a more declarative style.

So you want to return a product with specified id from an array list.
Since it is quite possible for the product to not be present, you could make ProductDB interface return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) of `Product`. That way the user of the interface has much clearer picture of what to expect.

Inside the get product function just get the [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from products list, filter the elements that have desired productId and return the first.

```
public class ProductDBImpl implements ProductDB{

    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public Optional<Product> getProduct(int productId) {

        return products.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getId() == productId)
            .findFirst();
    }
}
```